# Which key is used by spring security saml?

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, opensso

I am using spring security's open saml library for authentication.

My Service Provider is my spring web application configured with spring saml.
My IDP is OpenSSO.

In the spring-security-saml2-core library, the JKSKeyManager is never called, but the KeyManager gets called.

So is the library using the .jks keystore file as its keys or the 'apollo/nalle123' as its keys? what's their difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `org.springframework.security.saml.key.KeyManager` is an interface, `org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager` is its implementation. So if you see calls to `KeyManager`, in default configuration it means they're hitting the `JKSKeyManager`.

The `apollo/nalle123` key is stored inside the `.jks` file (`samlKeystore.jks` in the sample application), configured to be used by the `KeyManager`. `Apollo` is alias of the key in the `.jks` file, `nalle123` is its password.

Spring SAML combines usage of keys provided in the `KeyManager` and keys supplied in SAML metadata.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.
But if I change the .jks file on my OpenSSO to be from another instance of OpenSSO, while keeping the .jks file on my SP to be the same.  I am still able to validate successfully.
Especially at Line271 of AbstractProfileBase in spring-security-saml it validates successfully.  Is there something I am missing? Should it detect that the IDP and SP's .jks keys arent the same anymore?

Comment: How are you importing IDP metadata to your SP? Are the messages you're sending to SP digitally signed?

Comment: I copied the idp.xml and keystore.jks files generated by OpenSSO to my SP's war file.  And yes the SAML assertion sent from IDP to SP is signed (X509 Certificate).
Maybe I am mis-understanding the purpose of the .jsk file, does it come with a key or do we have to populate it with a key?

Comment: The default jks in Spring SAML comes with a private key aliased "apollo". This key is used to create digital signatures by Spring SAML. The metadata contains public key of your IDP which is used in SP to verify signatures created by the IDP. You should not be copying jks from OpenSSO to Spring SAML, as it contains private keys of OpenSSO which your SP should not have access to. I think that going through manuals of both OpenSSO and Spring SAML will help you better understand how is trust between IDP and SP established and configured. Also the SAML specification contains good information.